# Get the cartesian product of a series of tables in Python

Tags: python, cartesian-product

How can I get the Cartesian product from a group of tables?

I know how to get the cartesian product of **lists**. I use:

```
import itertools
for element in itertools.product(*somelists):
    print element
```

I am having trouble converting this into finding the cartesian product of two or more tables.

EDIT:

Example:

```
Table 1;
X: 1, 2, 4
A: a, b, d

Table 2;
X : 2,3,5
B : x,y,v
```

Output:

```
X: 1,1,1,2,2,2,4,4,4
A: a,a,a,b,b,b,d,d,d
X: 2,3,5,2,3,5,2,3,5
B: x,y,v,x,y,v,x,y,v
```

You can find a more visual example here:
http://web.utk.edu/sas/OnlineTutor/1.2/en/60477/m71/m71_3.htm

Comment: Could you provide some sample input/output for what you want to do? I'm struggling to imagine what it means to get the Cartesian product of anything other than one-dimensional sequences.

Comment: oh okay let me update the question

Comment: Rather, how have you stored the table!

Comment: In your example, what happened to the 3 in column X of table 1?

Comment: @DavidZ .. very sorry table 1 does not have a 3

Comment: Are tables dictionaries?

Comment: @selllikesybok .. I am actually opening a cvs file and that contains a table

Comment: Please show some example content of the `csv` file.

Comment: Python does not have any such data structure as a "table". If you have data in a CSV file that you want to work with, then first use the `csv` standard library module to load it into some structure, and then figure out what to do using `itertools.product` *and that structure*. It seems like this question is *really* asking about manipulating the file data, getting the cartesian product, and then formatting output in a certain way, making it too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
X A
1 a
2 b
4 d

X B
2 x
3 y
5 v
```

What needs to be done:

```
from pprint import pprint
t1 = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[4,'d']]
t2 = [[2,'x'],[3,'y'],[5,'v']]

t3 = []
for i1 in t1:
    for i2 in t2:
        i3 = i1 + i2
        t3.append(i3)
pprint(t3)
```

Result:

```
[[1, 'a', 2, 'x'],
 [1, 'a', 3, 'y'],
 [1, 'a', 5, 'v'],
 [2, 'b', 2, 'x'],
 [2, 'b', 3, 'y'],
 [2, 'b', 5, 'v'],
 [4, 'd', 2, 'x'],
 [4, 'd', 3, 'y'],
 [4, 'd', 5, 'v']]
```

Comment: python lists are so awesome! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
t1 = [ [1,2,4], 'abd' ]
t2 = [ [2,3,5], 'xyv' ]

def transpose(t):
    return zip(*t)

transpose(t1)
=> [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (4, 'd')]

for e1, e2 in itertools.product(transpose(t1), transpose(t2)):
    print e1 + e2  # concatenate the two tuples

(1, 'a', 2, 'x')
(1, 'a', 3, 'y')
(1, 'a', 5, 'v')
(2, 'b', 2, 'x')
(2, 'b', 3, 'y')
(2, 'b', 5, 'v')
(4, 'd', 2, 'x')
(4, 'd', 3, 'y')
(4, 'd', 5, 'v')
```

Comment: you have a typo. It should be `zip(*t)` and not `zip(*arr)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product
t1 = { 'X' : [1, 2, 4], 'A': ['a','b', 'd'] }
t2 = { 'X' : [2, 3, 5], 'B': ['x','y','v'] }
tables = [ t1, t2 ]
for rows in product([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]):
    print ", ".join(str(d[rows[i]]) 
            for (i, t) in enumerate(tables) 
                for d in t.values())
```

*Gives:*

```
a, 1, 2, x
a, 1, 3, y
a, 1, 5, v
b, 2, 2, x
b, 2, 3, y
b, 2, 5, v
d, 4, 2, x
d, 4, 3, y
d, 4, 5, v
```